# File upload in Ruby doesn't work when rendering it to another form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, upload, nested-forms

I am new to ruby and I would appreciate any kind of help. I have created a file uploader in ruby. When I test it separately, it works perfectly fine! But when I render it into another form, It just doesn't work! Here is my code:

upload/_index.html.erb

```
<h4>Upload File </h4>
<%= form_tag({:controller => 'upload', :action => 'upload_image'}, :multipart => true, remote: true) do %>
    <p><label for="upload_file">Select file..</label>
      <%= file_field 'upload', 'datafile' %></p>
    <%= submit_tag "Upload", :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg active", :method => 'post' %>
<% end %>
```

data_file.rb

```
class DataFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :upload
  belongs_to :event

  def self.save_file(upload)

    file_name = upload['datafile'].original_filename  if  (upload['datafile'] !='')
    file = upload['datafile'].read

    file_type = file_name.split('.').last
    new_name_file = Time.now.to_i
    name_folder = new_name_file
    new_file_name_with_type = "#{new_name_file}." + file_type

    directory = 'public/data'


    Dir.mkdir(directory + "#{name_folder}");
    File.open(directory + "#{name_folder}/" + new_file_name_with_type, "wb")  do |f|
      f.write(file)
    end

  end


end


upload_controller.rb

class UploadController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_filter do
    redirect_to :root unless current_user && current_user.isAdmin?
  end


  def index
   # @users = User.find(params[:id])
   redirect_to new_event_path
  end

  def upload_image
    DataFile.save_file(params[:upload])
    #redirect_to new_event_path
  end

  end
```

I have rendered upload/index into events/new.html.erb

```
<div style="margin-left: 360px;"><h1>New event</h1></div>
<br/>
<br/>

<div style="margin-left: 360px;">

  <%= form_for(:event, :url => {:controller => 'events', :action => 'new'}, html: { method: :post }) do |f| %>

      <% if @event.errors.any? %>
          <div id="error_explanation">
            <h2><%= pluralize(@event.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this event from being saved:</h2>

            <ul>
              <% @event.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                  <li><%= message %></li>
              <% end %>
            </ul>
          </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :event_Day %><br>
        <select name="event_day_id">
          <option value="0">-Choose agenda item-</option>
          <% for agenda_item in @agenda_items %>
              <option value="<%= agenda_item.id %>"><%= agenda_item.name %></option>
          <% end %>
        </select>
      </div>

      <%= link_to 'Add new agenda item', new_agenda_item_path %>
<br/>
      <br/>
      <div class="field">
        **<%= render :partial => 'upload/index' %>**
      </div>

      <br/>

      <div class="field">
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :Survey %><br>
          <select name="survey_id">
            <option value="0">-Choose survey-</option>
            <% for survey in @surveys %>
                <option value="<%= survey.id %>"><%= survey.title %></option>
            <% end %>
          </select>
        </div>
        <%= link_to 'Create new survey', new_survey_path %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg active", :method => 'post' %>
      </div>
  <% end %>

</div>

<%= button_to 'Back', events_path, :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg active', :method => 'get' %>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Refactor your answer is difficult to read and follow.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just noticed that the question was incomplete. I have answered the question though. When rendering the upload file form into another form, it does not work. So I removed it from the form and put it on top and everything is working fine.

Unless there is a way to nest once form inside the other?

Thanks!